# Maximal Ideals in a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the Ideal $I=(ux,uy,vx,uv)$ in the polynomial Ring $\mathbb Q[u,v,x,y]$, where $u,v,x,y$ are indeterminates. Prove or disprove that every maximal Ideal $M$, containing $I$ contains the Ideal $(u,v)$.

If I choose $M=(u,v^2+1,x,y)$ is my choice correct? How to prove that M contains I? If my choice is wrong what is the correct M? Please help.

Comment: To show $I \subset M$ you need only to show that $ux, uy, vx, vy$ are in $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $I$ is finitely generated, it is sufficient to show that each generator is contained in $M$.
Clearly $ ux = u*x$, hence it belongs to $M$. $ uy = u*y,  vx = xv = x*v, $ and $uv = u*v$ are all obtained by finite combination of generators of $M$. Thus generators of $ I $ are contained in $M $ and hence $ I \subseteq M$. To show <u,v> is not contained in $ M$, it is enough to show $ v \notin M$. If not, then $v \in M$ means that $M$ is same as the main ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ with indeterminates $ u,v,x,y$, which is a contradiction as $M$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @Brozovic Please point out the mistake. I am willing to correct my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider $M=(u^2+1,v,x,y)$ then clearly, $$\frac{\Bbb Q[u,v,x,y]}{M} \cong \frac{\Bbb Q[u]}{(u^2+1)}\cong \Bbb Q(i)$$

Hence $M$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Q[u,v,x,y]$ and as $v,x,y \in M$ it follows that $ux,uy,uv,vx \in M$ and thus $I \subset M$